# library not found for -lz for architecture armv7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

> error: Ld /Users/mymac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitness-drawjjdksjmgttbwvhjuzicescoz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Fitness/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Fitness.build/Release-iphoneos/Fitness.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Performance\ Society normal arm64

1. When i **Archive** app for app store then error generates.
2. When i run the app in simulator running well not any issue.
3. i am not using **pods**

please help me thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve my problem

1. in xcode **libz.dylib** file deleted.
2. so i get back this file from

   Get back my file to here `/usr/lib/libz.dylib`
3. And set my file here `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.4.sdk/usr/lib/`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

Click on your project (targets)

Click on Build Settings

Under Library Search Paths, delete the paths